# Android databinding register listener on xml for a custom button

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-databinding

Salam,
I wrote a custom button to support vector drawables. It works just great but when I try to register `onClick` listener in xml I get the following error

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.tomycab.fragments.NoTripFragment.openPromoDialog and android.view.View has 0 abstract methods, so is not resolved as a listener
  file:C:\Users\Ramdane\AndroidStudioProjects\NEW OLD\tomycab\app\src\main\res\layout\frag_no_trip.xml
  loc:261:51 - 261:71
  ****\ data binding error ****
```

Here is my `CustomButton` class code

```
package com.tomycab.custom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.DrawableCompat;
import android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import com.tomycab.R;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Created by ramdane on 9/18/17.
 */

public class CustomButton extends AppCompatButton implements View.OnClickListener {


    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomButton.class.getName());

    private String onClickName;
    private OnClickListener listener;
    private final Context context;
    private boolean inited = false;

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        initAttrs(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        initAttrs(context, attrs);
    }


    void initAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {

            TypedArray attributeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs,
                    R.styleable.CustomTextView);
            try {
                Drawable drawableLeft = null;
                Drawable drawableRight = null;
                Drawable drawableBottom = null;
                Drawable drawableTop = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    drawableLeft = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableLeftCompat);
                    drawableRight = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableRightCompat);
                    drawableBottom = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableBottomCompat);
                    drawableTop = attributeArray.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableTopCompat);
                } else {
                    final int drawableLeftId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableLeftCompat, -1);
                    final int drawableRightId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableRightCompat, -1);
                    final int drawableBottomId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableBottomCompat, -1);
                    final int drawableTopId = attributeArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableTopCompat, -1);

                    if (drawableLeftId != -1)
                        drawableLeft = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableLeftId);
                    if (drawableRightId != -1)
                        drawableRight = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableRightId);
                    if (drawableBottomId != -1)
                        drawableBottom = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableBottomId);
                    if (drawableTopId != -1)
                        drawableTop = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawableTopId);
                }


                int drawableTint = attributeArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomTextView_drawableTintCompat,
                        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorBlack));
                if (drawableLeft != null) {
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableLeft, drawableTint);
                }
                if (drawableRight != null) {
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableRight, drawableTint);
                }
                if (drawableTop != null) {
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableTop, drawableTint);
                }
                if (drawableBottom != null) {
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawableBottom, drawableTint);
                }

                setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableLeft, drawableTop, drawableRight, drawableBottom);
            } finally {
                attributeArray.recycle();
            }
            onClickName = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "onClick");
            inited = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
        if (!inited) {
            this.listener = l;
            super.setOnClickListener(this);

        } else {
            super.setOnClickListener(l);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener != null) {
            if (onClickName != null) {
                try {
                    Method m = context.getClass().getMethod(onClickName, View.class);
                    m.invoke(context, view);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex){
                    logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException ex){
                    logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex){
                    logger.log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
                }

            } else {
                listener.onClick(view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of the XML

```
<com.tomycab.custom.CustomButton
                        android:id="@+id/src_help"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/src_popup"
                        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/src_popup"
                        android:onClick="@{frag::onClick}"
                        />
```

Please note that I have set the frag variable correctly and tested it with a normal button and it works just fine

Comment: can you show the xml?

Comment: Hello, I just added the an example of XML. When I use the exact same syntax the code works just fine, but when I use it with my custom button I get the compile error.

Comment: Share `NoTripFragment` as well as the whole xml layout.

Comment: Please share the whole fragment java and xml code.

Comment: add `R.styleable.CustomTextView`

Comment: @RamdaneOualitsen Is this all the code that you are using, I don't want to leave anything behind when answering